# how do I fill table html to column wise?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to fill my table HTML using an API, however, I want to fill the given HTML table into a column instead of a row to look like the following image layout, but however, I am getting filled as row as you can see in my second image. is there a way to convert it into a column-based filling?

[image: layout]

row fill

[image: row_data]

```
const arr = [
  {
      "demo": [
          {
              "_id": "T0810",
              "title": "Historian",
              "tags": [
                  "demo"
              ],
              "queries": [],
          },
          {
              "_id": "T0817",
              "title": "book",
              "tags": [
                  "demo"
              ],
              "queries": [],
          },
      ],
      "demo_2": [
          {
              "_id": "T0875",
              "title": "Program",
              "tags": [
                  "demo_2",
                  "Control"
              ],
              "queries": [],
          },
          {
              "_id": "T0807",
              "title": "Interface",
              "tags": [
                  "demo_2"
              ],
              "queries": [],
          }
      ]
  }
]

const keys = Object.keys(arr[0]);

export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <table className="table">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  {keys.map((i) => (
                      <th key={i}>
                          <div className="column">
                              <div className="header">{i}</div>
                          </div>
                      </th>
                  ))}
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              {keys.map((key) => (
                  <tr key={key}>
                      {arr[0][key].map((item) => (
                          <td key={item._id}>
                              <div className="column">
                                  <div className="option">{item._id}</div>
                              </div>
                          </td>
                      ))}
                  </tr>
              ))}
          </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "column-based filling" and "row-based filling". Both of the images above have items in more than one column and more than one row...

Comment: @xdhmoore if you can see the frst image the `T0810, and T0817` are in the same row while it should be in column since `T0817` doesnt belong to column 2

Comment: I see. I think the problem is your outer loop iterates through the keys, but in html you have to specify rows, then columns. So your outer loop needs to be a row counter of some sort. You may need to find the maximum length of `arr[0][key]` for all possible keys and then use that as the max # of rows.

Comment: However, if I was trying this, I might try using css flex-box instead of a table. There is probably a more intuitive way to do it that way. But I'd have to go read through the docs to remember exactly how.

Answer (score 0):

It's only slightly more involved than what you have put together. The first thing you have to consider is that your table will have as many rows as the lengthiest key, so if `demo` array has 2 element and `demo_2` has 6 elements, the table will have 6 rows even though there will be nothing for 3 of those rows to display for `demo`.

As such your top level loop will have to loop not through `keys` but through a number representing the length of the lengthiest key, if that makes sense. So apart from getting the keys, you will need something like this:

```
const max_rows = keys.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (arr[0][cur].length > acc) return arr[0][cur].length;
  else return acc;
}, 0);
```

Then your nested loop will look like this:

```
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              {keys.map((i) => (
                <th key={i}>
                  <div className="column">
                    <div className="header">{i}</div>
                  </div>
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {Array(max_rows)
              .fill(0)
              .map((key, index) => (
                <tr key={index}>
                  {keys.map((item, ind) => (
                    <td key={ind}>
                      <div className="column">
                        {arr[0][item][index] ? (
                          <div className="option">
                            {arr[0][item][index]._id}
                          </div>
                        ) : null}
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  ))}
                </tr>
              ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Here is a Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-wave-5fub7?file=/src/App.js