# how do I Mock API and following the same approach as my static array?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rest

I have a React hooks component, which uses an HTML div-alike table to render data, and the data is being fetched from the server. I need to test the component to see if the table has data by mocking the API call. Below is the current code. I want to remove the use of `arr` completely and make avoid getting `{users}` rendered as `text/plain` as you can you in the below image

[image: mock_api_Call]

```
const arr = [
      {
          "demo": [
              {
                  "_id": "T0810",
                  "title": "Historian",
                  "tags": [
                      "demo"
                  ],
                  "queries": [],
              },
              {
                  "_id": "T0817",
                  "title": "book",
                  "tags": [
                      "demo"
                  ],
                  "queries": [],
              },
          ],
          "demo_2": [
              {
                  "_id": "T0875",
                  "title": "Program",
                  "tags": [
                      "demo_2",
                      "Control"
                  ],
                  "queries": [],
              },
              {
                  "_id": "T0807",
                  "title": "Interface",
                  "tags": [
                      "demo_2"
                  ],
                  "queries": [],
              }
          ]
      }];
      
    const keys = Object.keys(arr[0]);
    
    export default function Demo () {
      const [isModalOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false);
       const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
      
       const handleOnClick = async () => {
          try {
             const { data } = await axios.get('https://run.mocky.io/v3/0d7aa6e3-fc01-4a47-893d-7e1cc3013d4e');
             setUsers(data);
     
             // Now that the data has been fetched, open the modal
             setModalIsOpen(true);
           } catch (err) {
             console.error("failed", err);
           }
       };
     
     
       return (
         <div className="container">
             <>
               {keys.map((key) => (
                 <div className="col" key={key}>
                   <div className="row">{key}</div>
                     {arr[0][key].map((item) => (
                       <div className="row" key={item.technique_id} onClick={() => handleOnClick(item)}>{item.technique}</div>
                     ))}
                 </div>
               ))}
             </>
             {isModalOpen && <Modal onRequestClose={() => setModalIsOpen(false)} data={users}/>}
           </div>
       );
     }
```

Comment: Awfully familiar array... https://stackoverflow.com/q/66288688/1927991 You guys teaming up on it or what?

Comment: how can I move it?

Comment: I am confused. What do you mean by mocking the API call? Like  forcing the data to come through an async call? Or fake an http request?

Comment: @theJuls the force the data comes from a restful api where I have mock one from `https://run.mocky.io/v3/0d7aa6e3-fc01-4a47-893d-7e1cc3013d4e` , but how do I remove the use of `arr` ?

Comment: What do you mean remove the use of `arr`? You don't want to use it as test data and instead want to mock through the link you just sent on the comment above?

Comment: @theJuls yeah exactly

Comment: [**Please do not upload images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0):

Second attempt...Assuming I understand the ask then a package like Nock can do the trick (https://github.com/nock/nock).

The approach is to allow Nock to mock the API and return the result locally without calling the server. In your case it will be something like:

```js
const nock = require('nock');

const arr = [...]; // your original definition of arr

const scope = nock('https://run.mocky.io')
  .get('/v3/0d7aa6e3-fc01-4a47-893d-7e1cc3013d4e')
  .reply(200, arr);

// The rest of your code "as is"
...
```

This setup of Nock will intercept every HTTP call to `https://run.mocky.io` and will specifically return the content of `arr` in response to a `GET /v3/0d7aa6e3-fc01-4a47-893d-7e1cc3013d4e`.

Typically, I would not put this code in the main code.
Instead you can use it as part of a testing script that runs without dependency on an active server. E.g. testing during build.